# Configure Spring AMQP to use default bean for @RabblitListener's replyPostProcessor attribute

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Is there a way to configure all @RabbitListener annotations to use the same bean as value for the attribute `replyPostProcessor` ?

This is an example of using this attribute :

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = "test.header", group = "testGroup", replyPostProcessor = "echoCustomHeader")
public String capitalizeWithHeader(String in) {
    return in.toUpperCase();
}

@Bean
public ReplyPostProcessor echoCustomHeader() {
    return (req, resp) -> {
        resp.getMessageProperties().setHeader("myHeader", req.getMessageProperties().getHeader("myHeader"));
        return resp;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, no; feel free to open a new feature issue to add a property to the container factory. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues

**EDIT**

Work around:

```java
@Bean
public ReplyPostProcessor echoCustomHeader(AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactory<?> factory) {
    ReplyPostProcessor rpp = (req, resp) -> {
        resp.getMessageProperties().setHeader("myHeader", req.getMessageProperties().getHeader("myHeader"));
        return resp;
    };
    factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
        MessagingMessageListenerAdapter listener = ((MessagingMessageListenerAdapter) container
                .getMessageListener());
        listener.setReplyPostProcessor(rpp);
    });
    return rpp;
}
```

Comment: Issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1425#issuecomment-1055699443 where I added a work around.